# Avahi doesn't resolve reliably

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, dns, avahi

I have two computers, one running Ubuntu Desktop 20.04, the other running Ubuntu Server 20.04, lets call them desktop and server. I have installed avahi-daemon on them both. Desktop is a development station, while server is a fresh install with little installed past the defaults.

From desktop, avahi-browse shows several things on the network, including printers, cell phones, etc. However, it does not show server. If I restart the avahi-daemon on server I can resolve server.local for a minute or two, but then it stops resolving. Also, if I run `avahi-resolve-host-name server.local` on the server I can resolve server.local from desktop for a minute or two. I am maintaining a ssh connection to server the whole time, so I know it is still on the wifi.

From server, avahi-browse shows nothing, and I cannot resolve any .local device, other than server.local.

How do I make it so that I can reliably resolve server.local?

Comment: I've never found zero-conf networking of any flavor to be particularly reliable (avahi/zero-conf+SSDP/bonjour). The only advice I can give is to install a DNS server somewhere on your network.

Comment: Buggy Wi-Fi implementations lose multicast connectivity. It could be the Wi-Fi implementation in one or both of your machines, or your AP (Wi-Fi router). Experiment with pinging the "All Hosts" multicast address (224.0.0.1) from each device, to confirm or rule out that this is a multicast problem, not just mDNS. Make sure your AP does not have original WPA (TKIP) enabled or available in any way. Only WPA2 or later should be enabled/available. Trying to do both WPA2 and original WPA at the same time is extra tricky when it comes to multicast, and thus more likely to expose bugs.